How do I use Azure Trusted Signing to sign a word template (.dot)
I have followed the documentation and got trusted signing to work with .exe and MSI files.
I now have one last file type to resolve, a word template .dot file.
I have a script that signs the template with a local certificate that is working and I have altered that script to add the Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll /dlib. The command runs and says:
Trusted Signing

Version: 1.0.53

"Metadata": {
  "Endpoint": "https://weu.codesigning.azure.net/",
  "CodeSigningAccountName": "blahblah",
  "CertificateProfileName": "Moreblahblah",
  "ExcludeCredentials": [
    "VisualStudioCredential",
    "VisualStudioCodeCredential",
    "AzurePowerShellCredential",
    "InteractiveBrowserCredential"
  ]
}
Submitting digest for signing...
OperationId 1e21810d-2518-4598-918e-7eeb90d2b4e1: InProgress
Signing completed with status 'Succeeded' in 6.4137774s

but signtool returns C0000005 and the document is not signed.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr "http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com" /td SHA256 /dlib "C:\tools\signinglib\microsoft.trusted.signing.client\1.0.53\bin\x86\Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll" /dmdf "C:\sign-office\signing-metadata.json" "C:\Template.dot"

I am able to sign and verify using signtool after registering SIP from here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=56617
Command:
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\signtool.exe'  sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr "http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com" /td SHA256 /dlib x86/Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll /dmdf metadata.sample-scus.json .\sample.xlsm

Though I have tested with xlsm because I could not create .dot file (which is part of office 2003 I guess). If you can share then I can check with that too.

You can make a .dot file in word by saving as document as .dot.
I uploaded an example here too.
https://github.com/wyrdfish/ShareAndEnjoy/blob/master/ExampleDot/blank.dot

Trusted Signing does not support .dot file signing. Trusted Signing supports file types supported by SignTool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptography-tools

I understand but I am using the same signtool to sign the .dot now.
